# How to know if Android Wifi settings pane is on top?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to know if the Wifi settings pane is on top. I found this way:

```
ActivityManager a = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningTaskInfo> t = a.getRunningTasks( 1 );
if ( t.get( 0 ).topActivity.getClassName().equals( "com.android.settings.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity" ) )
{ 
    return true; // Yes it is!
}
else
{ 
    return false; // No it's not!
}
```

Actually, it works fine. But in Android reference doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) it is written that we should not use this method (read the link for more details). So *does somebody know how to perform this check in an other way?* Note that I target *SDK level 14 and higher*.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I need to display a window (Activity, ...) but sometimes my app will need to call the Wifi settings pane. So I need to know if this pane is on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Don't detect the settings pane, rather focus on why you would want to open the settings panel (you need WiFi connection and it is disabled, you need a particular SSID and the current one is not that one, ...).

For example, show your activity and if WiFi is disabled, show a popup to ask the user what he wants to do.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to open the Wifi setting panel, I want to do or not something else if the Wifi setting panel is on top. That's why I need to know if it is on top.